# Building a custom SQL querying tool that doesn't require the user to know SQL (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Hoping I can get some architectural advice on this.  I have been given the requirement to develop a "custom reporting" module that can basically enable the user to query any table in the database, without knowing SQL.  The idea as expressed to me is that the user should be able to use english-like way for saying what table they want, what fields they need to be displayed, any filtering they want, and now that they might need to create queries that have foreign key relationships in the DB.

My original idea was to present a "wizard" of sorts that would let the user 1) Select a table from a dropdown list, 2) Get a list of available columns, not all columns are allowed, via a custom attribute applied to special "Query" classes, and 3) Add a variety of filter queries using english-like nomenclature from dropdowns (e.g. "IS EQUAL TO" instead of "=", "IS IN" instead of "IN ()").

However, since I need to be able to know, seemingly magically, that if the user asks for x data I have to join tables together, I have no idea how to properly architect this or even if it's feasible (management seems to think it is...).

Any suggestions or advice on tackling something like this?  The users are external customers who will be accessing a website, not internal, so I can't just say "Let them use MS Access" or similar, but I can't just do a column name dump or give a big textbox for them to enter SQL queries, either.  The only way I can think of doing this is to have specific views for the data, but that defeats the vision of the module (not having to create views/procedures for every report a client would want).

**EDIT** Note we are not using Reporting Services; the "report" is really just a tabular GridView, not an SSRS report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**what ever you do, don't let them query the production database.**  They are bound to run some scary table scan that will crush the application's performance.

Just tell management that even the database OEMs haven't come up with a way to have end users easily get data from a database.  Your best bet is to use [SQL Server Analysis Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170208.aspx).  It really is the best way (to date) for end users to find their own data.

Comment: Would second the note about keeping adhoc user queries out of the main app database. Where we have needed to let users write their own queries we have moved the data over to a warehouse server and let the users have access to it there, not in the live app database.

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar problem with many of our products: the clients want the data, but they don't want the SQL involved.

Our cheap and easy solution was to make a button within the application that returns a gigantic CSV of the live database. They can then take it to their favorite program (Excel, SASS, ...) and utilize the data.

This probably isn't what you asked for, at all, but it is a cozy and comfortable alternative for both clients and programmers.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that would fly with management.  Out of curiosity though, did you handle foreign key relationships in that?  Or like just dump a huge thing with one CSV per table?

Comment: Sometimes fkeys were unavoidable but we tried to flatten tables as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it before but it is one that i had bookmarked for future examination..

[EasyQuery.NET WebForms](http://ajax.easyquerydemo.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with the wizzard kind of way - the user will select the tables he needs since the tables hold the columns. Therefore you know which tables you need to join. Only thing you need to keep track of is the n:m-relations - you could build something similar to the ms access interface. When the tables selected - present them in a er-diagramm and link the tables together - so the customer sees if the tables are connected.

I would build an QueryInterpreter that gets the information (table, columns, links, filters) and builds the SQL-query from it. Log the query, so if your customer complains that he does not receive the expected data - you could reverse-engineer his query and tell him how to use the tool correctly. Maybe build an Q&A-site for the most common mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx)?

This would create an OData model of all of your data, available over the web, which I think would eliminate the main hassle of constructing a lot of the queries. You could then worry on building a front end that would call the appropriate service to get the data and you could present it that way.

There's a [video](http://www.asp.net/aspnet-in-net-35-sp1/videos/adonet-data-services-with-aspnet-ajax-support) on the ASP.Net site on how to build a site using AJAX and WCF Data Services. There are also plenty of links on the WCF Data Services site as well.

Answer (score 0):

One **must** in my opinion is that you create a layer of views in your database that you will present to users to query. Well constructed views will prevent users from needing to do lots of extraneous joins and will give them a data structure that is much easier to understand. I'd use the views to do the following:

1. Mask any joins to lookup or other domain tables, instead surfacing user-friendly codes for domain data.
2. Perform selective denormalization of data, so that users don't need to think about joins when possible.
3. Provide consistent and user-friendly column names. Over time, our data structures can get mangled and end up with unobvious column names, so make sure that a user will understand every column that you surface.
4. Hide system-specific columns, such as AddDate, Timestamp, etc.

Without creating an exhaustive example, imagine you have a database that contains the following tables:

- **Customer** (ID, Name, Address)
- **Product** (ID, Name, Description, UnitPrice)
- **ShippingMethod** (ID, Name)
- **Order** (ID, CustomerID, OrderDate, ShippingMethodID, ShippingCost)
- **OrderDetail** (ID, OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, UnitPrice)

I would create the following views for user queries:

- **Order** (ID, CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerAddress,
  OrderDate, ShippingMethodName,
  ShippingCost)
- **OrderDetail** (ID, OrderID, ProductID, ProductName,
  ProductDescription, Quantity,
  UnitPrice)

It'll be much easier in my opinion for users to understand and query big flat views than fully normalized tables.

Comment: I agree, but the issue is we don't know what data they may want; we would have to create views for every possible scenario.  The purpose of the module is to let the users run any kind of query they want without knowing SQL and without IT involvement to create views.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the report builder module in reporting services?  I have not used it myself but from other reading I believe it is intended to support this type of scenario.

Comment: That was my first instinct but we aren't using Reporting Services, the "report" is basically just a GridView, so I cannot use Report Builder.

Comment: Might be worth pointing it out to people.  Unless the licensing has changed drasticly in the most recent versions you have already paid for it with your SQL Server licenses.  Setting up and securing a reporting environment would likely be lots quicker and cheaper than trying to build your own.

Comment: You are correct. Someone with SQL Server 2005 or 2008 already has a licensed version of Reporting Services, provided it is installed on the same server as the database. Installing it separately on another server requires another full SQL Server license.

Answer (score 0):

The most cost effective solution is to get Reporting Servers turned on, which comes with SQL Server 2005 and 2008. The cost of you developing such a robust product on your own can't beat the cost of configuring a product you already have a license for. The users can just use the Report Builder application that comes with SSRS. Speak to management about the costs, and they will listen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exposing it as a WCF data service, then using Excel Power Pivot to consume it. This allows for easy pivot tables and charts that business users love for what if scenarios.